# Error reported in web.config, but only when it is not open in the editor in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, web-config

I just changed to Visual Studio Community 2015 and I'm having a weird issue running a project. The project builds without any errors. But, when I go to start debugging I get the following error:

> There is an error in web.config. Please correct before proceeding. (You might rename the current web.config and add a new one.)

This only happens if `web.config` is not open in the editor in Visual Studio. If I open `web.config` in Visual Studio and try to run the project, I am able to do so and no errors are reported.

Comment: In the past, I have run into similar issues where the web.config looks malformed because there is a bomb character at the start of the file. Open the web. Config in vim and run "set nobomb". Maybe that will fix things

Comment: Tried that but didn't work, tried also replacing web.config with a new one created from vstudio but the error is still there if the file is closed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using any kind of web.config compiler that uses web.debug.config and web.release.config? I'm having a similar problem and am trying to narrow it down myself.

Comment: I tried deleting the config, and after I re-added it (actually, all of them - Dev, Debug & Release sub-types) to the solution, I noticed that Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config had a `<SubType>Designer</SubType>` node that went away, and the problem did as well. Web.config itself went from a simple `Content Include` to having `<SubType>Designer</SubType>`. Might be the cause of the problem, but then again, maybe not.

Comment: Still happens in 2019 .Net Framework API  application if anyone cares

Answer (score 52):

Has anyone suggested that we close and reopen Visual Studio?

Comment: you can just close the Web.config file if it's open in VS 2015 and that should take care of it as well, at least in my case, then rebuild and run

Comment: Notice how the question SPECIFICALLY AND CLEARLY states clearly that the Web Config file had to BE OPEN for him to debug successfully  Literally closed to get the error  yet you commented to close it

Comment: @ChristianProgrammer the question has been edited since he gave this answer.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in a Web API project in VS Enterprise 2015. I knew there was nothing wrong with the Web.config file because, like you, all I had to do was to have it open before hitting F5. It went away after I removed and re-added the project to the solution during solution re-organizing. You might want to try that. No logics here but then the error seems illogical too.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed/stopped the issue above and wanted to communicate what my fix was with the exact same symptoms as above.  I had switched to a different published environment when this started happening (from UAT to Dev) and I commented out a section in the web.config file.  Double checked to make sure I commented out the exact text.  I even cleaned my solution and rebuilt it, same problem.  Strangely, I could publish to the dev environment and the application would run (Web app with IIS 7).
The only difference between my local environment from when it was working and this problem was my web.config file.  So I was thinking VS was having trouble accessing the file when not open in the IDE.  I checked properties and the file had the appropriate settings.  I then checked in the solution into our source code repository and the issue went away.  We implement an SVN solution here.
Hope this helps.